# Element not visible with pyvirtualdisplay and selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying a simple browser operation where I locate a username element on a website and then try to login. I'm using selenium and python to do this. Here's some simple code that works on my own local machine. The code opens a browser on my computer and then navigates to the correct username box and enters the username.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(my_url)
username_element = browser.find_elements_by_name("USERNAME")[0]
username_element.clear()
username_element.send_keys(my_username)
```

However, when I try to deploy the same code on an AWS server using pyvirtualdisplay so that Firefox doesn't need to pop up, it no longer works.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(my_url)
username_element = browser.find_elements_by_name("USERNAME")[0]
username_element.clear()
username_element.send_keys(my_username)
```

The element is definitely found, but I get the element not visible error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

which is confirmed by:

```
>> username_element.is_displayed()
False
```

I've tried various things I found on SO including:

- making sure xvfb and xephyr are installed
- adding a `browser.implicitly_wait(30)`
- trying a `WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "USERNAME")))` which times out

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll screen:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 600)")
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm still getting the same not visible exception. I should note that the username box is at the top of the page, so it doesn't seem like it should be a scrolling problem.

Comment: you can take a screenshot to make sure that there is no the element on the page `browser.save_screenshot('screen.png')`

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped me figure it out. Turns out my screen size wasn't set large enough.

Comment: So in the answer i said about `scrollTo`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after taking a screenshot. Turns out my screen display wasn't set large enough. Changing the display size to (1600,900) solved the problem.